# Symfony AssetMapper and TypeScript - How can I fix "Cannot find module" linting error?

Tags: typescript, symfony, visual-studio-code, tsconfig, symfony-assetmapper

I have created a Symfony project using the [AssetMapper](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/asset_mapper.html) component alongside the [AssetMapperTypeScriptBundle](https://github.com/sensiolabs/AssetMapperTypeScriptBundle), as per the Symfony documentation.

I can successfully build and run my TypeScript Stimulus controllers as the AssetMapper is configured correctly, however I am getting a linting error I cannot solve.

[image: Linting error]

This is frustrating as it prevents type hinting and I want to fix it.

I have tried a few things, including:

- Changing the import to point directly at the file installed by the AssetMapper (in this case to `../vendor/@hotwired/stimulus/stimulus.index.js`). This technically removes the not found error, but still does not work as expected as there are no type hints.
- Creating a `tsconfig.json` file and specifying the path to the file, which does not work. (I tried a handful of variations on this path, none worked.)

[image: tsconfig layout]

- Installing `@types/stimulus` via the `importmap:require` command, but this results in an error.

[image: Stimulus types error message]

Is there something obvious (or not so much) that I'm missing?

Thanks.